# Grid gap disappears in the production build - react / styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, css-grid, styled-components

For reasons of compatibility in mobile browsers I need to use the Gap and Grid Gap properties in styled components.

The problem is when I compile the build producction. The grid-gap property disappears.

**dev**

[image]

**production**

[image]

I am using create react app.
"react": "^16.8.6"
"react-scripts": "3.0.1"
"styled-components": "^4.3.2"

These are the development and production commands:
"start": "react-scripts start"
"build": "react-scripts build"

Comment: Does it appear in all the browsers?

Comment: Does it. When is the development build

Comment: What about disappearing? does it disappear also from all the browser?

Comment: Yes. I just tried it on Chrome, Safari and Mozilla.

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of `npm list styled-components` for your project?

Comment: https://imgur.com/7Qc0Tvj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196444/discussion-between-sultan-h-and-renzo-telenta).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, using class gap-3 with tailwind didn't show up in production.

Example:

[image: class tailwind]

I don't know if it's the best way, but I overridden the css with !important and it worked

[image: override class]